# Background color in a table not displaying for empty cells

Tags: html, css, vue.js, css-selectors, background-color

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

I have a table, where I've given a gray background-color to every second row. How do I capture the empty cells here? And why aren't these being captured in this css:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd; 
}
```

Doing td:empty doesn't capture the blocks neither, so I'm a bit stumped.

Here's the html

```
      <td>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Add new email" v-model="email" />
            <img @click="addEmailToQ" src="@/assets/Plus.png" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- <h2>Emails</h2> -->
        <tr style="text-align: left" v-for="(email, key) in emailList" :key="key">
          {{email}}
        </tr>
      </td>
```

Comment: Please provide the full code for that table. Right now it looks like you have a `<td>` inside of a `<tr>` inside of a `<td>`? That seems a bit odd without more context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are including `<td>` in all cells, even empty `<td> </td>`

```css
tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #dddddd;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This was the crux of the issue, but Temani' answer led me to the solution :D

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your "error": It has nothing to do with CSS, your markup is simply wrong. `<tr>` needs to enclose `<td>`, not the other way around.

Read up on HTML Tables here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Sample code below: Empty cells will have the given background color with your CSS, if given the right markup.

```css
table {
  width:100%;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd; 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1, Cell 1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2, Cell 1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Argh! Thanks a lot :D